# What does it mean by negative determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I was watching 3b1b's videos on linear algebra. I cam across following points;

> 1. Negative determinant means orientation of space is reversed. If you assign dimensions to your fingers and if after transformation, if those assignments still hold, then it means orientation of space is not changed and Determinant is positive.
> 2. If after transformation the assignment hold on another hand, then space orientation is reversed and it means Determinant is negative.

**My doubts**

**Q1.** Can there be only two assignments, one to left hand and other to right hand?
**Q2.** If no, then can other assignments also mean reversal of space orientation and negative determinant? That is, after transformation, if assignments don’t hold (neither on left hand nor on right hand), then does it mean space orientation is reversed and Determinant is negative?

Comment: You can always make it so that your index finger points along the $x$-axis, in the positive direction, and your middle finger points along the $y$-axis, in the positive direction. Your thumb will then point along the $z$-axis. Either it points in the positive direction, or it points in the negative direction. There are no other possibilities. The direction of the thumb will be reversed if you change from right hand to left hand.

Comment: Maybe it is easier to grasp that the determinant multiplies with $-1$ , if any pair of columns or rows are exchanged. This is closely related to the change of the orientation.

Comment: I just fixed dimensions to both my hands. Then I folded my left thumb to point it in reverse direction. I realised that I can move /rotate my left hand to make left hand fingers point exactly in same direction as "corresponding" right hand fingers!!! Then I folded my index fingers to make it point in reverse direction. I realised that I can move/rotate my left hand to make left hand fingers point exacly in same direction as the original left hand finger direction!!!

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, you can visualise this in $3$ dimensions (or $2$ for that matter), but let's be more general. A length-preserving linear transformation of vectors is of the form $v\mapsto Rv$ with$$v^Tv=(Rv)^TRv=v^T(R^TR)v$$for all $v$, so $R^TR=I$. Taking determinants, $(\det R)^2=1$, i.e. $\det R=\pm1$. The right-handed choices of axes are related by matrices satisfying $\det R=1$, as are the left-handed ones, but to go from one to the other uses a matrix with $\det R=-1$. In particular, $\det R$ changes sign whenever we invert the direction of one axis, or exchange two axes.

Answer (score 0):

There are only two possible assignments, right hand and left hand.  Negative determinant means just what it  says.  You can compute the determinant by expansion by minors, or Laplace expansion, if  you have a square matrix.